Can the setting of The Wild Geese be deduced from the film itself?
The Wild Geese (1978) is largely set in a country in sub-Saharan Africa, where the fictional former president Julius Limbani has been deposed by the dictator General Ndofa. According to Wikipedia:

The African nation in the film is not named, but it is clearly meant to be Zaire (the modern Democratic Republic of the Congo).

Out-of-story details, such as the real-world "1968 landing of a mysterious aeroplane in Rhodesia that was said to have been loaded with mercenaries and "an African president" believed to have been a dying Moïse Tshombe" and Colonel Mad Mike Hoare serving as a military and technical advisor on the film after having fought for the Tshombe government in the Congo in 1964-1965, make it clear that indeed the country is meant to be Zaire/DRC. But what details, if any, in the film itself confirm this setting? Is it kept as an unnamed nation, or is the setting clear to the astute viewer?

There is actually geographical evidence in the film itself. From the scene when they're trying to make plans just after the plane turns around and abandons them:

JANDERS: The North is out of the question.
FAULKNER: Why? What if we got hold of a ferry to Burundi?
JANDERS: I wouldn't cross that lake even on a destroyer, Ndofa's men will pick us off like ducks. They wouldn't let us into Burundi anyway, nor Rwanda. Zambia's too far. East? 600 miles of jungle, totally impassable.
FAULKNER: That still leaves the South.

From which country can you cross a lake by ferry in order to reach Burundi?

We can see from the map that the only option that makes geographical sense is the DRC.

Well, there is the name of the movie.
Here is the arm patch of the 5 Commando unit of the Armée Nationale Congolaise.

The unit was nicknamed “The Wild Geese” in real life.
I understand that your question may be “Is there a connection between the country shown in the movie and the actual Zaire/DRC other than congruence between the military history of the country and the plot of the film, such as terrain, language, or even maps shown?”  If so, dunno.  Didn’t see it.
But two additional points:

there is a scene showing mining occurring
in another scene, the main characters fly from the unnamed country to Rhodesia (now Zimbabwe) in a clapped-out C-47.

So, a country near Zimbabwe with a mining industry.  That suggests either DRC or Zaire.

Mining plus proximity to Zimbabwe does not suggest the DRC in particular. The DRC has mining but it does not have a border with Zimbabwe. Botswana, Mozambique, and Zambia all have long borders with Zimbabwe and important mining sectors. Namibia and Angola have a lot of mining too. (I do think it was supposed to be the DRC though - see my answer.)

The presence of the Cuban army officer and the role of the character based on Tiny Rowland, taken together, put Zaire (now the Democratic Republic of the Congo) at the top of the list.
